# почему метод Mail::to($toEmails) в одном случае работает а в другом нет?

Tags: php, laravel-5.8

```
Mail::to($toEmails)->send(new ContactSend($feedback));
```

1) если написать в коде :

```
$toEmails = [
                  ['email' => 'email@cocom'],
                  ['email' => 'email2@cocom'],
            ];
```

то работает а

2)
если динамически то нет

```
$emails = explode(',', setting('site.request_emails') );
            $toEmails = [];
            $i=0;

            foreach ($emails as $email_item){
                $toEmails[$i]['email'] = $email_item;
                $i++;

            }
```

хотя переменная $toEmails во 2) случае если посмотреть в браузере через return выглядит как и 1)

```
вывод 1)
[{"email":"email@cocom"},{"email":"email2@cocom"}]

вывод для динамического 2)
[{"email":"john@gmail.com"},{"email":" john2@gmail.com"},{"email":" john3@gmail.com"}]
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101289/discussion-on-question-by-junior---mailtotoemails---).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, как выяснилось, просто добавляем пробел к $delimiter:

```
$emails = explode(', ', setting('site.request_emails') );
$toEmails = [];
$i=0;

foreach ($emails as $email_item){
    $toEmails[$i]['email'] = $email_item;
    $i++;
}
```